# Select parent & all children elements while using mouseover, jQuery

Tags: jquery, hover, toggle, selector, bind

I have a div with elements (h3, img, p) inside.  I want to use jQuery to detect when a user hovers over this div to then toggle a class of an element in this div.

I'm using the code below:

```
$('.entry').bind({
    mouseover: function() {
    $('.readMore').toggleClass('inverted');
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
    $('.readMore').toggleClass('inverted');
    }
});
```

This works as expected when hovering over just the `div`.  If you hover over an element inside the div (eg. `.entry h2`) it toggles the class off as though it has left the parent div (`.entry`) but it's actually inside it.  The elements are not floating inside `div.entry` which I had thought might throw it off.  I tried `$(".entry *")` and `$(".entry, .entry *")` but both of these have similar issues.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try using [`mouseenter`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter) and [`mouseleave`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave) instead.

Here's the relevant piece of documentation about `mouseenter` vs `mouseover`:

> The mouseenter event differs from mouseover in the way it handles
>   event bubbling. If mouseover were used in this example, then when the
>   mouse pointer moved over the Inner element, the handler would be
>   triggered. This is usually undesirable behavior. The mouseenter event,
>   on the other hand, only triggers its handler when the mouse enters the
>   element it is bound to, not a descendant.

[Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/2Pdwx/) that might help; note what events are fired off when you move your pointer in and out of elements.